# How to remove automatically added <br class="clear" >

Tags: css

I'm creating one wordpress template. Required information added in wordpress header.php, footer.php and everything was fine. Then i added one page. But while viewing the page there was a small problem just above the footer. After checking i found following code creating all the problems

```
<br class="clear">
```

But i didn't added that in page content. Somebody please tell me from where this thing came, and how to remove this?

Comment: WordPress doesn't add this, it'll be added by a plugin or your theme, I don't believe we can tell you where it came from without a full copy of the code of your site which would be impractical. You will need to search your codebase for that tag

Answer (score 0):

I afraid that added by some custom function or JavaScript because WordPress never add that tag by default. So use CSS to hide that element if you don't find that script

Answer (score -1):

at your theme functions add this line: `remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');`

Comment: @Eduart- That line already present, but still i'm getting the problem.

Comment: @programmer Can I have a link to check if it is online? Is it just under `the_content`? Or if you are using `the_content` in your theme can you try to use [get_the_content](http://codex.wordpress.org/get_the_content) instead

Comment: `wpautop` turns lines into paragraphs, it doesn't add `br` tags with clear classes